# Should I sign an APK that will be distributed just by side-loading

Tags: android, deployment

I'll distribute and APK by email and/or web link.

1. Should I sign it (Generate Signed APK) ?
2. What are the advantages of having it signed if I won't deploy it on Play Store?
3. Why there are erros that just show when building a Signed APK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

> Android requires that all apps be digitally signed with a certificate
>   before they can be installed. Android uses this certificate to
>   identify the author of an app, and the certificate does not need to be
>   signed by a certificate authority. Android apps often use self-signed
>   certificates. The app developer holds the certificate's private key.

Even in debug mode your app is signed with a debug key. If you want to give the apk file to your friends you should definitely sign it or else they won't be able to install the package (it will give a parser error).

On your second question, there are not any real advantages unless you actually deploy to the play store (when you would push an update for example, the update will install without any problems because it is signed with the same key).

On part 3, which errors are you receiving?

Comment: Errors: Things that I already solved, like to have just a empty contractor in DialogFragment classes. I didn't get these errors when building to debug.